# Why margin auto in flex makes vertical and horizontal centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here's a CSS question, if we put `margin: auto` in normal flow, only left and right margin space being averaged. However, if we put 'margin: auto` to a flex item, the item centered on both horizontal and vertical, why is it?

Heres the code:

```css
#one {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:solid 2px black;
    margin:auto;
    display:flex;
}

#two {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id = "one">
 <div id ="two"></div> 
</div>
```

Looking forward to any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality of the flex calculating the margin in all direction based on the parent div height and width,

i.e

1. The div#one having the height&width of 300px
2. The div#two having the height&width of 100px

so the margins are calculated as `margin:100px;`

Which means

```
#two{
margin-top:100px;
margin-right:100px;
margin-bottom:100px;
margin-left:100px;
}
```

If you need only horizontal margin then use `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: Is there any document specify that flex will calculate margin in all direction?

Comment: "Prior to alignment via justify-content and align-self, any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension."

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins

Comment: If you satisfied with the answer can u accept it ?

Comment: Great! Thank you nice man.